# I need a clue how to begin with this query

Tags: sql, oracle, express, variables, join

[image]

Picture shows how part of my DB looks like.

I want to have a ranking of players,  that shows for example ten best players from last week or so with sum of their points and nicknames which are stored in table *users*. I know that I need to sum points from *games_history*. The problem is I don't know how to associate users with their points and then sum up the whole thing.

Could anyone give me a clue?

Comment: are you only using games_history.user_1 or are you using all of the user_n fields?

Comment: All of the user_n fields. User_n is ID of the user in users, so i need to match user_n_points with user_n and then sum that up for every user.

Comment: can user_2 in one row also be user_1 in another row? Can games_history.user_n be null for any of the columns?

Comment: Yes, user_1 can have id 1 in one game and then id 2 in another game. So user_1_points in first game will be for user with id 1, but in second game it will be for user with id 2. User_3 and user_4 can be null, there must be two players to begin the game.

Comment: Show some code with some query that extract some table whose data is relevant to the solution. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Paraphrase or quote from other text. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Make your post self-contained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pivot your data, sum your scores, build a rank, then fitler however you want (date >= whatever, rank >= x). Something like this. Untested, but it'll get you started.

```
with mypiv as (
select gh.game_id, u.user_id, u.nickname,
       sum(case when gu.user_id = gh.user_1 then user_1_points
        when gu.user_id = gh.user_2 then user_2_points
        when gu.user_id = gh.user_3 then user_3_points
        when gu.user_id = gh.user_4 then user_4_points
        else 0 end) as points            
  from users  u
   ,games_history gh
 where 1=1
   and (u.user_id = gh.user_1 or
    u.user_id = gh.user_2 or
    u.user_id = gh.user_3 or
    u.user_id = gh.user_4)
group by gh.game_id,u.user_id, u.nickname)


select game_id, user_id, nickname, 
   rank() over (partition by game_id order by points) as myrank
from mypiv
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that returned me rankings for each game. Now, how do i sum up scores from all games for an overall ranking? What I mean is a ranking of players that ranks best player by sum of points from all games

Comment: If you don't want to rank by each game, just remove the "game_id" from the "partition by" clause and put in a dummy value:  select user_id, nickname, 
       rank() over (partition by '1' order by points) as myrank
from mypiv;